# Get fully rendered HTML using Selenium webdriver and Python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, iframe, webdriverwait

I'm trying to build a web scraper in Python using Selenium webdriver but I'm unable to access the information I need when I retrieve the website source code from webdriver.

I think the issue is that content is added to the page via JavaScript once the page has initially been downloaded from the server. When I run `browser.page_source` I get the source code of the page before this content was added. I want to know whether it is possible to get the source code of the page after the content loaded with JavaScript has been added (in other words what I see when I look at the page using Inspect Element).

Here is the basic Python script I'm using:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("https://www.opportunities.auckland.ac.nz")
print(browser.page_source)
```

When I run the above script I get the source code of the page I see when looking at the page source in the browser (i.e. without the additional content visible when the code is viewed with inspect element).

**Things I've tried**

- Adding `time.sleep(10)` in various places in case the page had not fully loaded when I was accessing the source.
- Using `get_attribute("innerHTML")` on the body.
- Using `execute_script()` to make the JS run.
- Using `execute_script()` to make the JS scripts run one by one.

It would be great if someone could tell be firstly whether this is possible and if it is point me in the right direction. Thanks.

**Update 1**

I get the following output when trying Piotrek's solution:

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/phantomjs/webdriver.py", line 49
warnings.warn('Selenium support for PhantomJS has been deprecated, please use headless '
UserWarning: Selenium support for PhantomJS has been deprecated, please use headless versions of Chrome or Firefox instead
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
```

Unfortunately this seems not to work.

Comment: Inspect the source you want with DOM and use WebDriverWait with presence_of_element_located for an element that's only present after the JS executes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The desired elements are within an `<iframe>`, so you have to use *WebDriverWait* for the *iframe to be available, and then switch to it*,  then again use *WebDriverWait* for the *elements to be visible*.

You can use following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  driver = webdriver.Chrome()
  driver.get("https://www.opportunities.auckland.ac.nz")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,"ptifrmtgtframe")))
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@id='HRS_APPL_WRK_HRS_PAGE_TITLE']")))
  print(driver.page_source)
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  <!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="pc chrome win psc_dir-ltr psc_form-xlarge" dir="ltr" lang="en"><!-- Copyright (c) 2000, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved. --><head>
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <script type="text/javascript" async="" src="https://ssl.google-analytics.com/ga.js"></script><script language="JavaScript">
  var  totalTimeoutMilliseconds = 2073600000; 
  var  warningTimeoutMilliseconds = 2073600000; 
  var timeOutURL = 'https://www.opportunities.auckland.ac.nz/psp/ps/EMPLOYEE/HRMS/?cmd=expire';
  var timeoutWarningPageURL = 'https://www.opportunities.auckland.ac.nz/psc/ps/EMPLOYEE/HRMS/s/WEBLIB_TIMEOUT.PT_TIMEOUTWARNING.FieldFormula.IScript_TIMEOUTWARNING';
  var sRCRequestURL = 'https://www.opportunities.auckland.ac.nz/psc/ps/EMPLOYEE/HRMS/s/WEBLIB_PTRC.ISCRIPT1.FieldFormula.IScript_RC_REQUEST';
  </script> 

  <link id="PSSTYLEREQ_1_css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/cs/ps/cache/PSSTYLEREQ_1.css" />
  <link id="UOA_STYLE_SWAN_1_css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/cs/ps/cache/UOA_STYLE_SWAN_1.css" />
  <title>Applicant Home</title>
  <script language="JavaScript">
  try {
  document.domain = "opportunities.auckland.ac.nz";
  }
  catch(err) {;}
  </script>
  <script language="JavaScript">
  var winName='win0';
  var winParent = null;
  var modalID = null;
  var modalZoomName = null;
  var baseKey_win0 = "\x1b\r\n";
  var altKey_win0 = "05678\xbc\xbe\xbf\xde";
  var ctrlKey_win0 = "JKM";
  var saveWarningKeys_win0 = "";
  var refererURL = 'https://www.opportunities.auckland.ac.nz/psp/ps/EMPLOYEE/HRMS/c/HRS_HRAM.HRS_CE.GBL?languageCd=ENG';
  var isNewSaveWarn = true;
  var bAccessibility_win0 =false;
  var bFMode =false;
  var bDoModal_win0 = false;
  var bJSModal_win0 = false;
  var bPromptPage_win0 = false;
  var bTabOverTB_win0 = false;
  var bTabOverPg_win0 = false;
  var bTabOverNonPS_win0 = false;
  var PIA_KEYSTRUCT={HRS_PERSON_ID:"0"};
  var strCurrUrl='https://www.opportunities.auckland.ac.nz/psp/ps/EMPLOYEE/HRMS/c/HRS_HRAM.HRS_CE.GBL?HRS_PERSON_ID=0&amp;PAGE=HRS_CE_HM_PRE';
  var bIncInNavigation='F';
  var szCrefID='HC_HRS_CE_GBL2';
  var szCrefReged='T';
  var szCrefVisible='F';
  var szCrefLabel='Careers';
  bGenDomInfo = false;
  var szCalendarType = 'G';
  var bMenuSrchPage = false;
  var bWSRP=0;var szMenuSrchText = "-999999-";
  var disablePNSubscriptions=1;var modalCloseUrl = '/cs/ps/cache/PT_TRANS_16PIX_1.png';
  var modalCloseAlt = 'Close';
  var modalResizeUrl= '/cs/ps/cache/PT_RESIZE_IMG_1.gif';
  var modalResizeAlt = 'Drag to resize';
  var modalMoveAlt = 'Drag to move';
  </script>
  <script language="JavaScript">
  var gridList_win0 = [
  ['HRS_CE_JO_EXT_I$0',0,56,0,1,1]
  ];
  var gridHeaderList_win0 = [
  [['HRS_CE_JO_EXT_I$0#0',1]]
  ];
  var gridRowSelRgbColor_win0 ='rgb(173,216,230)';
  var gridFieldList_win0 = [
  ['HTMLAREA$%c',
  'HRS_CE_JO_EXT_I$new$%c$$0',
  'HRS_CE_JO_EXT_I$delete$%c$$0']
  ];
  </script>
  <script language="JavaScript">
  var PFieldList_win0 = [['HRS_SCH_WRK_ESTABID',1],['HRS_ESTAB_I_DESCR',1]];
  </script>
  <script language="JavaScript">
  try {
  document.domain = "opportunities.auckland.ac.nz";
  }
  catch(err) {;}
  </script>
  <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="/cs/ps/cache/PT_COMMON_MIN_1.js">
  </script>
  <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="/cs/ps/cache/PT_AJAX_NET_MIN_1.js">
  </script>
  <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="/cs/ps/cache/PT_SAVEWARNINGSCRIPT_MIN_1.js">
  </script>
  <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="/cs/ps/cache/PT_PAGESCRIPT_win0_MIN_1.js">
  </script>
  <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="/cs/ps/cache/PT_EDITSCRIPT_win0_MIN_1.js">
  </script>
  <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="/cs/ps/cache/PT_RC_JS_MIN_1.js">
  </script>
  <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="/cs/ps/cache/PT_POPUPSCRIPT_win0_MIN_1.js">
  </script>
  <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="/cs/ps/cache/PT_GRIDSCRIPT_win0_MIN_1.js">
  </script>
  <link id="UOA_HDR_LOGO_1_css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/cs/ps/cache/UOA_HDR_LOGO_1.css" />
  <link id="UOA_HDR_BANNER_1_css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/cs/ps/cache/UOA_HDR_BANNER_1.css" />
  <link id="UOA_FOOTER_BANNER_1_css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/cs/ps/cache/UOA_FOOTER_BANNER_1.css" />
  <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="/cs/ps/cache/UOA_GA_JS_MIN_1.js">
  </script>
  <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="/cs/ps/cache/PT_TYPEAHEAD_win0_MIN_1.js">
  </script>
  <script language="JavaScript">
  var nResubmit=0;
  var nLastAction=0;
  var loader=null;
  if (typeof(bCleanHtml) == 'undefined')
      var bCleanHtml = false;
  setupTimeout2();
  var postUrl_win0='https://www.opportunities.auckland.ac.nz/psc/ps/EMPLOYEE/HRMS/c/HRS_HRAM.HRS_CE.GBL';
  function aAction_win0(form, id, params, bAjax, bPrompt)
  {
  setupTimeout2();
  if ((id != '#ICSave'))
  processing_win0(1,3000);
  aAction0_win0(form, id, params, bAjax, bPrompt);
  }
  function submitAction_win0(form, id, event)
  {
  setupTimeout2();
  if (!ptCommonObj2.isICQryDownload(form, id))
   { processing_win0(1,3000); }
  preSubmitProcess_win0(form, id);
  var spellcheckpos = id.indexOf('$spellcheck');
  if ((spellcheckpos != -1) &amp;&amp; (id.indexOf('#KEYA5') != -1))
      form.ICAction.value = id.substring(0,spellcheckpos);
  else 
      form.ICAction.value=id;
  var actionName = form.ICAction.value;
  form.ICXPos.value=ptCommonObj2.getScrollX();
  form.ICYPos.value=ptCommonObj2.getScrollY();
  bcUpdater.storeBcDomData();
  if ((typeof(bAutoSave) != 'undefined') &amp;&amp; bAutoSave)
      form.ICAutoSave.value = '1';
  if (!ptCommonObj2.isAJAXReq(form, id) &amp;&amp; !ptCommonObj2.isPromptReq(id)){
  if (nLastAction == 1 &amp;&amp; nResubmit &gt; 0) return;
  form.ICResubmit.value=nResubmit;
  form.submit();
  if (!ptCommonObj2.isICQryDownload(form, id))
      nResubmit++;
  }
  else if (ptCommonObj2.isPromptReq(id))
      pAction_win0(form, id, arguments[2]);
  else
      aAction_win0(form, actionName);
  cancelBubble(event);
  }
  </script>
  <script language="javascript">
  var pt_calHeadstyle=" class='PTCALHEAD' "
  var pt_calWeekHeadstyle=" class='PTCALWEEKHEAD' "
  function dateitemrefs()
  {
  this.pt_dateheader = "/cs/ps/cache/PT_PORTAL_IC_CLOSE_SD_SWAN_1.gif";
  this.pt_datering = "/cs/ps/cache/PT_CURRENT_DATE_SD_CSS_1.gif";
  this.pt_datesel = "/cs/ps/cache/PT_SELECTED_DATE_SD_CSS_1.gif";
  this.pt_nextmonth = "/cs/ps/cache/PT_RIGHT_SCROLL_SD_SWAN_1.gif";
  this.pt_prevmonth= "/cs/ps/cache/PT_LEFT_SCROLL_SD_SWAN_1.gif";
  this.pt_daystitle_hijri = "/cs/ps/cache/PT_DATE_TITLE_S6_1.GIF";
  this.pt_daystitle_thai = "/cs/ps/cache/PT_DATE_TITLE_S0_1.GIF";
  this.pt_daystitle_s0 = "/cs/ps/cache/PT_DATE_TITLE_S0_1.GIF";
  this.pt_daystitle_m1 = "/cs/ps/cache/PT_DATE_TITLE_M1_1.GIF";
  this.pt_daystitle_t2 = "/cs/ps/cache/PT_DATE_TITLE_T2_1.GIF";
  this.pt_daystitle_w3 = "/cs/ps/cache/PT_DATE_TITLE_W3_1.GIF";
  this.pt_daystitle_t4 = "/cs/ps/cache/PT_DATE_TITLE_T4_1.GIF";
  this.pt_daystitle_f5 = "/cs/ps/cache/PT_DATE_TITLE_F5_1.gif";
  this.pt_daystitle_s6 = "/cs/ps/cache/PT_DATE_TITLE_S6_1.GIF";
  }

  function LoadCalendar()
  {
  var dateitems = new dateitemrefs();
  loadImages(dateitems);
  }
  function DatePrompt_win0(dtfield,promptfield,yrfmt,bsubmit)
  {
  setupTimeout2();
  openDate_win0(dtfield, promptfield, "DMY/"+yrfmt,bsubmit,"G",0);
  }
  </script>
  <script language="JavaScript" ptdefer="defer">
  if (typeof ptStyleSheet == "undefined") {
  ptStyleSheet = 'UOA_STYLE_SWAN';
  }
  function onLoadExt_win0() {
  modalZoomName = null;
  var oWin=window;
  var oDoc=document;
  ptTAObj_win0.init(oWin,oDoc,oDoc.win0,'/cs/ps/cache/PT_SRT2UP_SEL_1.gif','/cs/ps/cache/PT_SRT2DN_SEL_1.gif','/cs/ps/cache/PT_PORTAL_IC_CLOSE_1.gif',500);
  var pt_pageinfo = document.getElementById('pt_pageinfo_win0');
  if (pt_pageinfo) {
  pt_pageinfo.setAttribute('Page', 'HRS_CE_HM_PRE');
  pt_pageinfo.setAttribute('Component', 'HRS_CE');
  pt_pageinfo.setAttribute('Menu', 'HRS_HRAM');
  pt_pageinfo.setAttribute('Mode', 'CLASSIC');
  }
  g_bAccessibilityMode=false;
  var actn='';
  setKeyEventHandler_win0();ptEvent.add(window,'scroll',positionWAIT_win0);
  ptCommonObj2.generateABNSearchResults(document.win0);
  getGblSrchPageNum(actn);
  if (gSrchRsltPageNum &lt;= 5) getAllRelatedActions();

  ptCommonObj2.moveUnivSrchDiv();
  if (typeof(ptLongEditCounter) != 'undefined' &amp;&amp; ptLongEditCounter != null)
     ptLongEditCounter.onLoadLongEditCounter();
  if (typeof(HelppopupObj_win0) != 'undefined' &amp;&amp; HelppopupObj_win0 != null)
   HelppopupObj_win0.StopPopup('win0');
  doModalOnLoad_win0(false, false);
  ResetGlyph_win0();
  self.scroll(0,0);
  ptGridObj_win0.initGriddd854();objToBeFocus = null;
  if (typeof oWin == 'undefined') setEventHandlers_win0('ICFirstAnchor_win0', 'ICLastAnchor_win0', false);
   else
   oWin.setEventHandlers_win0('ICFirstAnchor_win0', 'ICLastAnchor_win0', false);
  setFocus_win0('HRS_SCH_WRK_ESTABID',-1);
  ptLoadingStatus_empty(0);
  setupTimeout2();
  processing_win0(0,3000);
  ptConsole2.enable();

  UpdateBreadCrumbs();
  GenerateABN();
  GenerateFakeBC();
  bcUpdateForPTF();if (typeof(myAppsWindowOpenJS) != 'undefined' &amp;&amp; myAppsWindowOpenJS != null &amp;&amp; myAppsWindowOpenJS != '')
   {
  try {eval(myAppsWindowOpenJS);} catch(e) {}
    myAppsWindowOpenJS=null;
  }
  ResetGlyph_win0();setPageletInfoInCtxmenu_win0("false");
  GetDomData(win0, "TargetContent", "#GetDomInfo");
  }
  try{ptEvent.load(onLoadExt_win0);}catch(e){}
  </script></head>
  <body tabindex="-1" class="PSPAGE">
  <div id="pt_pageinfo_win0" page="HRS_CE_HM_PRE" component="HRS_CE" menu="HRS_HRAM" mode="CLASSIC"></div>
  <form id="HRS_CE" name="win0" method="post" action="https://www.opportunities.auckland.ac.nz/psc/ps/EMPLOYEE/HRMS/c/HRS_HRAM.HRS_CE.GBL" autocomplete="off" class="PSForm">
  <div class="ps_box-toolshiddens" id="win0divPSTOOLSHIDDENS"><div class="ps_modalmask_cover psc_hidden" id="pt_modalMaskCover"> </div><div class="ps_modalmask psc_hidden" id="pt_modalMask"> </div><div id="pt_modals" class="PSMODAL"><div id="ptModalShadow" class="popupDragFrame" style="cursor:nw-resize"> </div></div>
  <div class="ps_ajax_console psc_hidden" id="pt_console"><input type="button" id="COPYCONSOLE" value="Copy" onclick="ptConsole2.copy();" alt="copy to clipboard" title="copy to clipboard" /><input type="button" id="CLEARCONSOLE" onclick="ptConsole2.clear();" value="Clear" alt="clear console" title="clear console" /><input type="button" id="HIDECONSOLE" onclick="ptConsole2.hide();" value="Hide" alt="hide console" title="hide console" /><input type="button" id="CLOSECONSOLE" onclick="ptConsole2.deactive();" value="Close" alt="close console" title="close console" /></div><div class="ps_typeahead psc_hidden" id="pt_typeahead0" style="display: none;"><span id="pt_typeahead" class="spanTextDropdown"> </span></div><div id="WAIT_win0" style="display: none; position: absolute; right: 0px; z-index: 99991; visibility: hidden;"><img id="processing" align="left" src="/cs/ps/cache/PT_PROCESSING_1.gif" alt="Processing... please wait" title="Processing... please wait" /></div>
   <div id="SAVED_win0" style="display: none; position: absolute; right: 0px; z-index: 99991; visibility: hidden;"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tbody><tr><td><img src="/cs/ps/cache/PTPORTAL_POPBOX_LEFT_1.gif" width="7" height="39" border="0" alt="" /></td><td id="saveWait_win0" width="35" align="center" valign="middle" background="/cs/ps/cache/PTPORTAL_POPBOX_CENTER_1.gif"><img src="/cs/ps/cache/PT_LOADER_1.gif" width="24" height="24" alt="" /></td><td nowrap="nowrap" background="/cs/ps/cache/PTPORTAL_POPBOX_CENTER_1.gif"><span id="ptStatusText_win0" dir="ltr" class="PSPROCESSING"> </span></td><td><img src="/cs/ps/cache/PTPORTAL_POPBOX_RIGHT_1.gif" width="6" height="39" alt="" /></td><td> </td></tr></tbody></table></div><div class="x" id="win0divPSHIDDENFIELDS" style="display:none"><input type="hidden" name="ICType" id="ICType" value="Panel" />
  <input type="hidden" name="ICElementNum" id="ICElementNum" value="0" />
  <input type="hidden" name="ICStateNum" id="ICStateNum" value="1" />
  <input type="hidden" name="ICAction" id="ICAction" value="None" />
  <input type="hidden" name="ICXPos" id="ICXPos" value="0" />
  <input type="hidden" name="ICYPos" id="ICYPos" value="0" />
  <input type="hidden" name="ResponsetoDiffFrame" id="ResponsetoDiffFrame" value="-1" />
  <input type="hidden" name="TargetFrameName" id="TargetFrameName" value="None" />
  <input type="hidden" name="FacetPath" id="FacetPath" value="None" />
  <input type="hidden" name="ICFocus" id="ICFocus" value="" />
  <input type="hidden" name="ICSaveWarningFilter" id="ICSaveWarningFilter" value="0" />
  <input type="hidden" name="ICChanged" id="ICChanged" value="-1" />
  <input type="hidden" name="ICAutoSave" id="ICAutoSave" value="0" />
  <input type="hidden" name="ICResubmit" id="ICResubmit" value="0" />
  <input type="hidden" name="ICSID" id="ICSID" value="iGf8pba3GL6SnwAoi3ZMca4P0dLE1k7Nqh632XOcc84=" />
  <input type="hidden" name="ICActionPrompt" id="ICActionPrompt" value="false" />
  <input type="hidden" name="ICTypeAheadID" id="ICTypeAheadID" value="" />
  <input type="hidden" name="ICBcDomData" id="ICBcDomData" value="" />
  <input type="hidden" name="ICFind" id="ICFind" value="" />
  <input type="hidden" name="ICAddCount" id="ICAddCount" value="" />
  <input type="hidden" name="ICAPPCLSDATA" id="ICAPPCLSDATA" value="" />
  <input type="hidden" name="HRS_CE_JO_EXT_I$hnewpers$0" id="HRS_CE_JO_EXT_I$hnewpers$0" value="0|0|0|0|0|567|0#" />
  </div>
  </div>
  <a name="ICFirstAnchor_win0" id="ICFirstAnchor_win0"></a>
  <div class="ps_header_panel" id="PT_HEADER_PANEL"></div>
  <div class="" id="win0divPAGEBAR"></div>
  <div class="ps_box-pagetabs" id="win0divPSPANELTABS"></div>
  <div class="ps_pagecontainer" id="win0divPAGECONTAINER"><table class="PSPAGECONTAINER" role="main" aria-labelledby="app_label"><tbody><tr><td>
  <div class="ps_pspagecontainer" id="win0divPSPAGECONTAINER"><table role="presentation" border="0" id="ACE_width" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="PSPAGECONTAINER" cols="12" width="1042">
  <tbody><tr>
  <td width="2" height="7"></td>
  <td width="7"></td>
  <td width="542"></td>
  <td width="83"></td>
  <td width="29"></td>
  <td width="1"></td>
  <td width="2"></td>
  <td width="1"></td>
  <td width="251"></td>
  <td width="117"></td>
  <td width="2"></td>
  <td width="5"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td height="4" colspan="7"></td>
  <td colspan="5" rowspan="3" valign="top" align="left">
  <div id="win0divHRS_APPL_WRK_HRS_APP_LOGIN"><span id="HRS_APPL_WRK_HRS_APP_LOGIN$span" class="PSHYPERLINK" title="Login"><a name="HRS_APPL_WRK_HRS_APP_LOGIN" id="HRS_APPL_WRK_HRS_APP_LOGIN" ptlinktgt="pt_replace" tabindex="64" onfocus="doFocus_win0(this,false,true);" href="https://www.opportunities.auckland.ac.nz/sso-login" target="_top" class="PSHYPERLINK">Sign in/Register</a></span>
  </div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td height="23" colspan="2"></td>
  <td colspan="5" valign="top" align="left">
  <div id="win0divHRS_APPL_WRK_HRS_PAGE_TITLE"><span role="heading" aria-level="1" class="PAPAGETITLE" id="HRS_APPL_WRK_HRS_PAGE_TITLE">Career Opportunities</span>
  </div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td height="2" colspan="2"></td>
  <td rowspan="2" valign="top" align="left">
  <div id="win0divHRS_APPL_WRK_HRS_APP_INFO_GPB"><table role="presentation" border="0" id="ACE_HRS_APPL_WRK_HRS_APP_INFO_GPB" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" cols="5" width="541" class="PSGROUPBOX" style="border-style:none">
  <tbody><tr>
  <td width="15" height="0"></td>
  <td width="2"></td>
  <td width="428"></td>
  <td width="52"></td>
  <td width="44"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td height="4" colspan="2"></td>
  <td colspan="2" valign="top" align="left">
  <div id="win0divHRS_CE_WRK_HRS_ERROR_LOGIN"><div style="width:480px; ">
  <!-- Begin HTML Area Name Undisclosed -->

  <!-- End HTML Area -->
  </div>
  </div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td height="20"></td>
  <td colspan="2" valign="top" align="left">
  <div id="win0div$ICField11"><table role="presentation" border="0" id="ACE_$ICField11" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" cols="2" width="429" class="PAERRORTEXT" style="border-style:none">
  <tbody><tr>
  <td width="9" height="0"></td>
  <td width="420"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td height="20"></td>
  <td valign="top" align="left">
  <div id="win0divHRS_APPL_WRK_HRS_PAGE_INSTR"><span class="PAPAGEINSTRUCTIONS" style="word-wrap:break-word;overflow:hidden;display:block; width:420px;  overflow:auto;" id="HRS_APPL_WRK_HRS_PAGE_INSTR"> </span>
  </div></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody></table>
  </div></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody></table>
  </div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td height="31" colspan="2"></td>
  <td colspan="4" rowspan="2"></td>
  <td colspan="5" rowspan="3" nowrap="nowrap" valign="top" align="left">
  <div id="win0divHRS_APP_CAR_DRV_HRS_RCMNT_LNK"><span id="HRS_APP_CAR_DRV_HRS_RCMNT_LNK$span" class="PSHYPERLINK"><a name="HRS_APP_CAR_DRV_HRS_RCMNT_LNK" id="HRS_APP_CAR_DRV_HRS_RCMNT_LNK" ptlinktgt="pt_new" tabindex="65" onfocus="doFocus_win0(this,false,true);" href="http://www.auckland.ac.nz/uoa/home/about/careers-at-auckland/faqs" onclick="window.open('http://www.auckland.ac.nz/uoa/home/about/careers-at-auckland/faqs','','');cancelBubble(event);return false;" class="PSHYPERLINK">Frequently Asked Questions</a></span>
  </div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td height="10" colspan="3"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td height="5"></td>
  <td colspan="3" rowspan="6" valign="top" align="left">
  <div id="win0div$ICField153"><table role="presentation" border="0" id="ACE_$ICField153" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" cols="2" width="631" class="PSFRAME" style="border-style:none">
  <tbody><tr>
  <td width="0" height="7"></td>
  <td width="631"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td height="883"></td>
  <td valign="top" align="left">
  <div id="win0divHRS_APPL_WRK_HRS_JOB_POST_GPB"><table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" cols="1" class="PSGROUPBOXWBO" width="635">
  <tbody><tr><td class="PSGROUPBOXLABEL" align="left">Latest Career Opportunities</td></tr>
  <tr><td width="631">
  <table role="presentation" border="0" id="ACE_HRS_APPL_WRK_HRS_JOB_POST_GPB" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" cols="3" width="631" class="PSGROUPBOX" style="border-style:none">
  <tbody><tr>
  <td width="0" height="1"></td>
  <td width="632"></td>
  <td width="1"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td height="14"></td>
  <td colspan="2" valign="top" align="left">
  <div id="win0div$ICField54"><table role="presentation" border="0" id="ACE_$ICField54" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" cols="4" width="635" class="UOA_PSCHARTCOLOR1" style="border-style:none">
  <tbody><tr>
  <td width="32" height="2"></td>
  <td width="300"></td>
  <td width="176"></td>
  <td width="127"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td height="12"></td>
  <td nowrap="nowrap" valign="top" align="left">
  <div id="win0divUOA_CG_SRCH_TITLE"><span id="UOA_CG_SRCH_TITLE$span" class="UOA_PABOLDTEXT" title="Title"><a name="UOA_CG_SRCH_TITLE" id="UOA_CG_SRCH_TITLE" ptlinktgt="pt_peoplecode" tabindex="71" onclick="javascript:cancelBubble(event);" href="javascript:submitAction_win0(document.win0,'UOA_CG_SRCH_TITLE');" class="UOA_PABOLDTEXT">Job Title</a></span>
  </div></td>
  <td nowrap="nowrap" valign="top" align="left">
  <div id="win0divUOA_CG_SRCH_TITLE1"><span id="UOA_CG_SRCH_TITLE1$span" class="UOA_PABOLDTEXT" title="Title1"><a name="UOA_CG_SRCH_TITLE1" id="UOA_CG_SRCH_TITLE1" ptlinktgt="pt_peoplecode" tabindex="70" onclick="javascript:cancelBubble(event);" href="javascript:submitAction_win0(document.win0,'UOA_CG_SRCH_TITLE1');" class="UOA_PABOLDTEXT">Campus</a></span>
  </div></td>
  <td nowrap="nowrap" valign="top" align="left">
  <div id="win0divUOA_CG_SRCH_TITLE2"><span id="UOA_CG_SRCH_TITLE2$span" class="UOA_PABOLDTEXT" title="Title2"><a name="UOA_CG_SRCH_TITLE2" id="UOA_CG_SRCH_TITLE2" ptlinktgt="pt_peoplecode" tabindex="69" onclick="javascript:cancelBubble(event);" href="javascript:submitAction_win0(document.win0,'UOA_CG_SRCH_TITLE2');" class="UOA_PABOLDTEXT">Close Date</a></span>
  </div></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody></table>
  </div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td height="10" colspan="3"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td height="840"></td>
  <td valign="top" align="left">
  <div id="win0divHRS_CE_JO_EXT_I$0"><table cellspacing="0" class="PSLEVEL1GRIDNBO" id="HRS_CE_JO_EXT_I$scroll$0" dir="ltr" cellpadding="0" cols="1" height="842" width="632"><tbody><tr><td align="center" valign="top"><div id="divgcHRS_CE_JO_EXT_I$0" style="width:632px;height:842px;" class="psprintgrid">
  <table id="l0HRS_CE_JO_EXT_I$0" style="width:632px;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tbody><tr><td>
  <div id="divgbHRS_CE_JO_EXT_I$0" style="width:632px;height:842px; " class="psprintgrid"><table id="gbHRS_CE_JO_EXT_I$0" style="overflow:hidden;" class="psprintgrid" dir="ltr" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="632">
  <tbody><tr><td class="psprintRightTd" style="width:632px;" valign="top">
  <div id="divgbrHRS_CE_JO_EXT_I$0" style="width:632px;height:812px; overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:scroll;" class="psprintgrid" onscroll="ptGridObj_win0.doOnScroll('HRS_CE_JO_EXT_I$0',1);"><table id="tdgbrHRS_CE_JO_EXT_I$0" border="0" style="width:614px;" dir="ltr" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" cols="1"><tbody><tr id="trHRS_CE_JO_EXT_I$0_row1" onclick="HighLightTR('rgb(173,216,230)','','trHRS_CE_JO_EXT_I$0_row1');" onmouseover="hoverLightTR('rgb(196,194,189)','',0,'trHRS_CE_JO_EXT_I$0_row1');" onmouseout="hoverLightTR('rgb(196,194,189)','',1,'trHRS_CE_JO_EXT_I$0_row1');"><td align="center" id="tdHRS_CE_JO_EXT_I$0#0" height="23" class="PSLEVEL1GRIDROW">
  <div id="win0divHTMLAREA$0"><div style="width:563px; ">
  <!-- Begin HTML Area Name Undisclosed -->
  <!--
  * Project:   Project Octane
  * Developer: Remylou Sioson
  * Date:      November 2011
  * Details:   HTML for the layout of Job postings in Careers page.
  -->
  <table>
  <tbody><tr>
  <td class="PSHYPERLINK" width="352" align="left"><a href="javascript:submitAction_win0(document.win0,'#ICSetFieldHRS_CE_HM_PRE.POSTING_TITLE$0.1');" title="Job Title">Business Analyst</a></td>
  <td class="PSEDITBOX_DISPONLY" width="200" align="left">Auckland City Campus</td><td class="PSEDITBOX_DISPONLY" width="100" align="left">25/09/2018</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="PSEDITBOX_DISPONLY" colspan="3" width="100%" align="left"><p><span style="font-family:arial,sans-serif"><span style="font-size:9.0pt">We are seeking a Business Analyst to support key projects and initiatives across the University, enabling key delivery teams, projects and initiatives to improve and innovate the University’s services.</span></span></p></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody></table>
  <!-- End HTML Area -->
  </div>
  </div>
  </td>
  </tr><tr id="trHRS_CE_JO_EXT_I$0_row2" onclick="HighLightTR('rgb(173,216,230)','','trHRS_CE_JO_EXT_I$0_row2');" onmouseover="hoverLightTR('rgb(196,194,189)','',0,'trHRS_CE_JO_EXT_I$0_row2');" onmouseout="hoverLightTR('rgb(196,194,189)','',1,'trHRS_CE_JO_EXT_I$0_row2');"><td align="center" height="23" class="PSLEVEL1GRIDROW">
  <div id="win0divHTMLAREA$1"><div style="width:563px; ">
  <!-- Begin HTML Area Name Undisclosed -->
  <!--
  * Project:   Project Octane
  * Developer: Remylou Sioson
  * Date:      November 2011
  * Details:   HTML for the layout of Job postings in Careers page.
  -->
  <table>
  <tbody><tr>
  <td class="PSHYPERLINK" width="352" align="left"><a href="javascript:submitAction_win0(document.win0,'#ICSetFieldHRS_CE_HM_PRE.POSTING_TITLE$1.1');" title="Job Title">Senior Lecturer in Clinical Pharmacology (part time)</a></td>
  <td class="PSEDITBOX_DISPONLY" width="200" align="left">Grafton Campus</td><td class="PSEDITBOX_DISPONLY" width="100" align="left">07/10/2018</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="PSEDITBOX_DISPONLY" colspan="3" width="100%" align="left"><p><span style="font-family:arial,sans-serif">Alongside our full time Senior Lecturer/Associate Professor opportunity, we seek to appoint a part time Senior Lecturer in Clinical Pharmacology at approximately 16 hours per week.<span style="font-size:9.0pt"> </span></span></p></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody></table>
  <!-- End HTML Area -->
  </div>
  </div>
  </td>
  </tr><tr id="trHRS_CE_JO_EXT_I$0_row3" onclick="HighLightTR('rgb(173,216,230)','','trHRS_CE_JO_EXT_I$0_row3');" onmouseover="hoverLightTR('rgb(196,194,189)','',0,'trHRS_CE_JO_EXT_I$0_row3');" onmouseout="hoverLightTR('rgb(196,194,189)','',1,'trHRS_CE_JO_EXT_I$0_row3');"><td align="center" height="23" class="PSLEVEL1GRIDROW">
  <div id="win0divHTMLAREA$2"><div style="width:563px; ">
  <!-- Begin HTML Area Name Undisclosed -->
  <!--
  * Project:   Project Octane
  * Developer: Remylou Sioson
  * Date:      November 2011
  * Details:   HTML for the layout of Job postings in Careers page.
  -->
  <table>
  <tbody><tr>
  <td class="PSHYPERLINK" width="352" align="left"><a href="javascript:submitAction_win0(document.win0,'#ICSetFieldHRS_CE_HM_PRE.POSTING_TITLE$2.1');" title="Job Title">Research Fellow</a></td>
  <td class="PSEDITBOX_DISPONLY" width="200" align="left">Tamaki Campus</td><td class="PSEDITBOX_DISPONLY" width="100" align="left">24/09/2018</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="PSEDITBOX_DISPONLY" colspan="3" width="100%" align="left"><p><span style="font-family:arial,sans-serif"><span style="font-size:9.0pt">On offer: an exciting opportunity to join the internationally-renowned NIHI nutrition team in the role of Research Fellow. </span></span></p></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody></table>
  <!-- End HTML Area -->
  </div>
  </div>
  </td>
  </tr><tr id="trHRS_CE_JO_EXT_I$0_row4" onclick="HighLightTR('rgb(173,216,230)','','trHRS_CE_JO_EXT_I$0_row4');" onmouseover="hoverLightTR('rgb(196,194,189)','',0,'trHRS_CE_JO_EXT_I$0_row4');" onmouseout="hoverLightTR('rgb(196,194,189)','',1,'trHRS_CE_JO_EXT_I$0_row4');"><td align="center" height="23" class="PSLEVEL1GRIDROW">
  <div id="win0divHTMLAREA$3"><div style="width:563px; ">
  <!-- Begin HTML Area Name Undisclosed -->
  <!--
  * Project:   Project Octane
  * Developer: Remylou Sioson
  * Date:      November 2011
  * Details:   HTML for the layout of Job postings in Careers page.
  -->
  <table>
  <tbody><tr>
  <td class="PSHYPERLINK" width="352" align="left"><a href="javascript:submitAction_win0(document.win0,'#ICSetFieldHRS_CE_HM_PRE.POSTING_TITLE$3.1');" title="Job Title">Regulatory Approvals Administrator- Fixed-term</a></td>
  <td class="PSEDITBOX_DISPONLY" width="200" align="left">Auckland City Campus</td><td class="PSEDITBOX_DISPONLY" width="100" align="left">07/10/2018</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="PSEDITBOX_DISPONLY" colspan="3" width="100%" align="left"><p><span style="font-size:12px"><span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif"><em><span style="color:black">Are you talented administrator looking for a part-time, fixed-term role?</span></em></span></span></p><p><span style="font-size:12px"><span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif"><em><span style="color:black">Are you interested in applying your skills in the dynamic tertiary environment?</span></em></span></span></p></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody></table>
  <!-- End HTML Area -->
  </div>
  </div>
  </td>
  </tr><tr id="trHRS_CE_JO_EXT_I$0_row5" onclick="HighLightTR('rgb(173,216,230)','','trHRS_CE_JO_EXT_I$0_row5');" onmouseover="hoverLightTR('rgb(196,194,189)','',0,'trHRS_CE_JO_EXT_I$0_row5');" onmouseout="hoverLightTR('rgb(196,194,189)','',1,'trHRS_CE_JO_EXT_I$0_row5');"><td align="center" height="23" class="PSLEVEL1GRIDROW">
  <div id="win0divHTMLAREA$4"><div style="width:563px; ">
  ```

Comment: Thanks, looks like this works to get the info I need on that page so I should be able to modify it to do what I want.

Comment: the unnecessary use of Options in this answer just confuses things.  I am removing them.

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into a similar problem once, what helped me was using `PhantomJS()` instead of `Chrome()` (even though Selenium support for PhantomJS has been deprecated):

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()
browser.get("https://www.opportunities.auckland.ac.nz")
print(browser.page_source)
```

Comment: See my edit to the original question. This seems like it does not work. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: yeah, i get the same warning, but then if you wait a bit the page_source loads correctly

Comment: Waiting for 15 seconds gets me the source but it doesn't have the additional content loaded (i.e. It's the same as viewing the page source in browser) so still no joy. Again, thanks for the suggestion.