# checking if a string is on a webpage - Selenium Webdriver retrieves static HTML code but not the Elements full code (and the string contents)

Tags: python, html, css, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to check if a specific string element appears on a  URL webpage. My webdriver retrieves the HTML source code with no issues:

```
URL = "******"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)
html_source_code = driver.page_source
print(html_source_code)
```

I still haven't found a way to pull the exact HTML code as it appears on the elements inspection mode. The Selenium always retrieves some sort of a static code  - but never the elements script itself.
so let's say the HTML elements inspection paragraph in the code I'm after (that's the element on the script highlighted when I'm hovering over the **desired_string** on the webpage)

```
<a _ngcontent-serverapp-**="">******</a>
<a _ngcontent-serverapp-**desired_string**="" class="is-current-section">
   *******</a>
```

(I've made the desired_string on bold as on the inspection elements code it appears on a black font).
My script is aimed at flagging once the 'desired_string' is on the inspection elements script, is that the only way to corroborate that the desired_string actually appears on the webpage? (unless there's a way to make Selenium scrap the text directly from the webpage interface).
I've also tried to use the element xpath itself:

```
/html/body/meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="**"/app-root/***-details/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/nav/a[2]/text()
```

and find the element attributes through the driver:

```
print(driver.find_element("xpath",""""/html/body/meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="***"/app-root/***-details/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/h1""").get_attribute("innerHTML").splitlines()[0])
```

But am getting selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException:

```
Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression "/html/body/meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="*"/app-root/*-details/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/h1 because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string is not a valid XPath expression
```

.

So my question remains the same, how do you corroborate that a specific string appears on the webpage (whilst knowing that the string is embedded in the HTML elements inspection code, but Selenium would never retrieve the whole exact code?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52428409/get-fully-rendered-html-using-selenium-webdriver-and-python

Comment: You'll want to use webdriverwaits with expected conditions.  Right now you don't wait for JS to fully render the page after page load.  You don't need to get the page source, just use a proper webdriverwait and/or sleep after the get().   I suggest a sleep, and then use find_elements to get an array with webdriverwait and expected condition of visibility of all elements located by XPATH that matches what you are testing for.  If the returned array is size 0, the condition has failed.  (no elements match the locator)